# Android update manager clear data & clear cache

Tags: android

My Android application uses an update manager. Is this a method that can be added in an if else statement? If the user updates this application the update manager should help to clear data & cache.

```
//Version Update
if (obj.has("ForceCode")) {
    int ForceCode = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("ForceCode"));
if (ForceCode < 0) {
    GoMain();
} else {
    if (ForceCode == 0) {   //Force Update
        url = obj.getString("URL").toString();
        if (!url.equals(""))
            new com.romobi.fortune.update.UpdateManager(LoginActivity.this, url);
    }
    if (ForceCode == 1) {   //Remind Update
        String Version = obj.getString("Version");
        url = obj.getString("URL").toString();
        dialog = new MyDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Version Update",
                "There is New version available(" + Version + ")You Need to be update to log in.", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (!url.equals(""))
                    new com.romobi.fortune.update.UpdateManager(LoginActivity.this, url);
            }
        }, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //GoMain();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
} else {
    GoMain();
}
```